# RequestFactory: Create a proxy by hand for unit testing

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I want to test a custom cell that takes a `MyDomainProxy extends EntityProxy` as a parameter. The custom cell renders a different cell depending on the value of `MyDomainProxy.getState()`. For instance it can render a `TextCell` or a `SelectionCell`.

The test I want to run is:

```
MyDomainProxy proxy = ... <- I don't know how to do that part.
MyCell cell = new MyCell();
cell.setActiveCell(proxy);
assertTrue(cell.getActiveCell() == MyCellType.TEXT_CELL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally ended up using `Mockito`.

```
MyDomainProxy proxy = Mockito.mock(MyDomainProxy.class);
when(proxy.getState()).thenReturn(DomainState.DELETED);
```